# Error while creating custom Library in codeigniter - Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$MyLib

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written below controller `welcome.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library('MyLib');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function demo(){

        /*$this->load->library('MyLib');*/
        $this ->MyLib->hello();
    }
}
```

I have written below code in application/libraries `MyLib.php`

```
<?php


class MyLib{

    public function hello(){

        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

[This error I am getting while calling the demo function of controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cpYZ.png)

Comment: try writing name MyLib in small letters.

Answer (score 1):

You should use it in lowercase when loading in a controller.

**Ref:** https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

> The Library file name should be `Mylib.php` and the Library class name should be `Mylib`.
>
> **$this->load->library('mylib');**

**Controller - Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library('mylib'); //Use it in lowercase.
    }

    public function demo(){
       $this->mylib->hello(); //Use it in lowercase.
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to create new variable like this to use that class :

```
$myLib = new MyLib();
$myLib->hello();
```